# Get selected value from select list

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have this part here, which i use in order to print some values in a list:

```
<select id = "paisja" name="paisja" >
<?php
while( $row = odbc_fetch_array($resultpaisja) ) {
?>

 <option value="<?php echo $row['id_paisje']; ?>"><?php echo $row['paisje']; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
```

Now, what i need is if i print the list of this order, the list should appear again but with the selected value...
Some Help Please?
Thanks

Comment: when you print out the list, mark some option as selected.

Comment: The question is not clear... You cannot access the selected property in php to do actions as that is only available in the DOM after the page is loaded and php is only server side. You can force an option to be selected from PHP though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take note of the added PHP code block in the select options. [UPDATED]

```
<select id = "paisja" name="paisja" >
<?php while( $row = odbc_fetch_array($resultpaisja) ) {

$default_select_id = 1; //Set a default ID

if(isset($_REQUEST['paisja']) && $_REQUEST['paisja'] == $row['id_paisje']){ 
  $select = ' selected="selected" '; //Set from submitted value
} elseif ($row['id_paisje'] == $default_select_id) {
  $select = ' selected="selected" ';  //Set from default ID if no submitted value
}

?>
 <option value="<?php echo $row['id_paisje']; ?>"  <?php echo $select; //Execute the selection ?> >
<?php echo $row['paisje']; ?>
</option>
<?php
}

?>
```

Comment: At least now you can set the default ID to select when your page loads. When you select and submit the form to the same page, the value of the select would be used to set the next select. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<option <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['paisja']) && $_REQUEST['paisja'] == $row['id_paisje']){?>selected="selected"<?php } ?> value="<?php echo $row['id_paisje']; ?>"><?php echo $row['paisje']; ?></option>
```

Added : `<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['paisja']) && $_REQUEST['paisja'] == $row['id_paisje']){?>selected="selected"<?php } ?>` in option tag.

Comment: @pyetjegoo. This should work, resubmit the form and let's see what you get.

Comment: i don't get any error at all, but the issue is i just get the first value of the list

Answer (score 0):

You could try to get the value from the selected index by using the post method

example:

```
    echo '<select name="paisja">';
    while( $row = odbc_fetch_array($resultpaisja))
    {
        echo'<option value="'. $row["id_paisje"] .'">' . $row["paisje"] . '</option>';
    }
   echo '</select><br />';



    echo $_POST['paisja']; //will output the selected value
```